# Trigonometric derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello everyone how would I solve the following derivative.

$f(x)=5x^3\tan(x)+\cot(2x)$

I know the derivative of $\tan(x)$ is $\sec^2(x)$

So would I do

$15x^2\sec^2(x)-\csc(2x)$

As my derivative.

Comment: Product rule...

Comment: yes in the first term I think.I have to use it.

Comment: Also, as a note on the vocabulary, you do not "solve" a derivative (there is no equation), but rather "find" the derivative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that you have a product of two functions in the first term:
$$
5x^3\tan(x).
$$
So you need to use the product rule. You get (for the first term only)
$$
\frac{d}{dx} 5x^3\tan(x) = \left[\frac{d}{dx}5x^3\right]\tan(x) + 5x^3\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x).
$$

Also for the second term
$$
\cot(2x)
$$
you need to multiply by the derivative of the "inner function" $2x$ (using the Chain Rule here):
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \cot(2x) = -\csc^{\color{red} 2}(2x)\frac{d}{dx}(2x).
$$

Comment: On the second term do you mean the to use the chain rule?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: That is exactly right.

Comment: So for my final answer I got $15x^2\tan(x)+5x^3\sec^2(x)-\csc^2(2x)(2)$

Comment: yes It should be $15x^2$ I went back and corrected my error.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Now it looks right to me :) And: no problem. Glad to help.

Comment: As a matter of style, I would prefer $2\csc^2(2x)$ towards the end of your expression. That's because, particularly if you do further processing in a problem, it might be easy to misread $\csc^2(2x)(2)$ as meaning $\csc^2(4x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first term or any term as two separate functions multiplied i.e.
 f (x) . g (x)
Derivative is given by the formula
 f'(x).g (x) + g'(x).f (x)  where f'(x) denotes derivative of f with respect to x.

So for your first term 5x^3 tan(x) 
= d(5x^3)/dx × tan (x) +**d** tanx/**dx** × 5x^3  which is
15x² tanx+sec²x 5x³

now for your cot(2x)
chain rule shall be applied to function 
dcot2x/dx=dcot2x/d2x × d 2x/dx
this yeilds to 2csc2x now add them up and you have your answer.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing math.